# What's the source of a custom not to eat meat at seudo shlishis?

Tags: minhag, shabbat, meat, meal-seudah

Recently I hosted a traveller for Shabbos meals who follows a custom of not eating meat at seudo shlishis. (He would usually eat fish instead.)

What is the origin/source of this custom and how widespread is it?

Answer (score 7):

R. Pinchas Zavichi quotes a source for this custom. He begins by quoting [R. Yissachar Dov Rokeach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yissachar_Dov_Rokeach_(third_Belzer_rebbe)) who proved that the post-Shabbat meal must have been dairy in the times of Israel's wanderings in the wilderness, because based on various legal rules there would have been no meat available for consumption on Saturday night. R. Zavichi then goes on to quote from [R. Shalom of Belz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Rokeach) that one should not eat meat at the third Shabbat meal in order to be able to drink coffee with milk at the post-Shabbat meal:

**[Tashit L'Rosho, Halachot V'Hanhagot Motzaei Shabat Kodesh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49043&st=&pgnum=215&hilite=)**

> ועי' בס' חי וקיים בענין סעודה רביעית (עמוד קלג) שהביא שם כי פעם אחת
>   האדמו"ר מהרי"ד מבעלז זיע"א ראה כמה אנשים שיושבים ואוכלים סעודה רביעית
>   וראה שהם אוכלים מאכלי חלב בסעודה זאת ואמר להם תאמרו לי מהיכן מרומז
>   בתורה הקדושה שבמדבר אכלו סעודת מלוה מלכה במאכלי חלב ולא ידעו לענות לו
>   ואמר להם היות שבשר תאוה נאסר לישראל לאכול במדבר על כן היו מוכרחים
>   לאכול בשר שלמים ושלמים הרי נאכלים לשני ימים ולילה אחד ונמצא ששלמים
>   שנשחטו בערב שבת קודש אכלו אותם כל יום ערב שבת קודש ובליל שבת קודש קודש
>   וביום שבת קודש עד הלילה והיות שאין שוחטין קודשים בלילה לא היה להם שום
>   בשר לאכול במוצאי שבת קודש ועל כרחם אכלו מאכלי חלב עכד"ק יעו"ש ואכן
>   כעין זה הובא עוד נמי בס' מקור חיים (אות ל) בשם הגאון הקדוש רבי מאיר
>   יחיאל הלוי מאוסטרובצה זיע"א יעו"ש ובס' י"ג אורות ח"ב (עמוד רלה) הביא
>   דהגה"ק רבינו שלום מבעלז זיע"א אמר שלא לאכול בשר בסעודה שלישית כדי
>   שיוכלו לשתות קפה עם חלב במוצאי שבת בסעודת מלוה מלכה יעו"ש

This custom is also mentioned by [R. Yisrael Chaim Friedman](https://www.geni.com/people/R-Yisroel-Chaim-Friedman/6000000006816702646). He says that he has seen many righteous people and holy people who did not eat meat at the third meal, but instead ate fish.

**[Likutei Maharich, Seder Seudah Shelishit](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41190&st=&pgnum=153)**

> וכן ראיתי אצל כמה צדיקים וקדושים שלא אבלו בשר בסעודה זו רק דגים

R. Yechezkel Shraga Frankel also mentions from R. [Yechezkel Shraga Halberstam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Shraga_Halberstam) that the custom in [Sieniawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieniawa) was to not eat meat at the third meal, but no reason is given.

**Rabbeinu Hakadosh M'Sieniawa p. 662**

> הגה"ק מציעשנוב דבק בכל ישותו באביו וכל דרכיו והליכותיו היו בהתאם
>   למנהגיו אולם היו מעט דברים בהם שינה ממנהגי אביו כגון  אבילת דגים
>   בסעודת יום שב"ק מנהג שבשינאווא לא נהגו בו ואף רבינו הורה לו להדיא שאין
>   אוכלים אז דגים והוסיף דטעם הדבר כאותה סיבה שאין אוכלין בשר בסעודה
>   שלישית

Comment: ויאמר משה בתת יהוה לכם בערב בשר לאכל

Comment: @DoubleAA צריך עיון

Comment: @DoubleAA As far as I remember, there was no prohibition of בשר תאווה (according to those who believe there was such a prohibition) on animals / birds which could not be used as sacrifices (including quail). I realize that this make the question on the Belzer Ruv stronger.

Comment: Also worth noting that this doesn't work according to [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Ritual_Slaughter.4.17?lang=bi) כְּשֶׁהָיוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל בַּמִּדְבָּר לֹא נִצְטַוּוּ בִּשְׁחִיטַת הַחֻלִּין אֶלָּא הָיוּ נוֹחֲרִין אוֹ שׁוֹחֲטִין וְאוֹכְלִין כִּשְׁאָר הָאֻמּוֹת

Comment: Belz seems to suggest that *Melavah Malka* is a requirement. Does he state that it is required? If not, and oen does not plan to to do it, then what's the problem of eating meat during *Shalosh Seudot*?

Comment: @DanF [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 300:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1507).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the source but I recall hearing that we (by we I mean Ashkenazim) don't eat meat at seudah shlishis because David HaMelech died on Shabbos afternoon.
I believe that some Yemenites have a custom to specifically eat meat at the third meal.
I think there are some Sephardim who have no specific custom against it and sometimes they do eat meat and other times not at seudah shlishit.
Has anyone met someone who specifically had the custom to eat meat at the third meal?